# simplest way to return a new list by remove index/value from another list? (order required)

Tags: python, list, indexing

All,

```
o1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]

index = [3,4]
value = ["c","d"]


[x for x in o1 if x not in value] 
[x for x in o1 if x not in [o1[y] for y in index]]
```

any simpler solution for above lc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(x for x in o1 if x not in value)
(x for i, x in enumerate( o1 ) if i not in index )
```

Note that using generator expressions will save you a pass through the list, and using sets instead of lists for index and value will be more efficient.